# Reading Sqlite files with a "light" dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a small disk cleaner, only about 400 KB in size. In order to clean Firefox, I need access to their places.sqlite.

Which is fine, I used those System.Data.Sqlite.dll and it works good.

However, the problem is they are 1.1MB. Which is like the dobule the size of my disk cleaner. I honestly would like like to increase the download size of my program from 400kb to 1.5mb.

Is there a way I can slim the dll or maybe use another type of method to access places.sqlite?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried to rebuild the source in release config, but that leads to all sorts of errors.

Comment: Is it 32-bit dll on x64?

Comment: I was pretty sure I was using the 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid using including the 1MB dll in your program is the only choice. I don't think there are any method to 'compress' this dll.  And even 1.5MB is still a very small file size.

Comment: Well that's sad. Anyway, since yours is the only answer, I guess i'll accept it as the correct.